# Problem about migration to Version 2.0 of Linkedin API

Tags: rest, linkedin-api

recently linkedin has sent a reminder email:

> **Important update:** All developers need to migrate to Version 2.0 of our APIs and OAuth 2.0 by March 1, 2019. Learn more

I'm using Linkedin Rest API to get user information after the authorization.
The old v1 api was:
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~

Looking at the migration guide found here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/migration-faq?context=linkedin/consumer/context

this request has to be changed. I tried to make the following requests:

https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me

to get user basic info (as first_name and last_name)

and then:

https://api.linkedin.com/v2/emailAddress?q=members&projection=(elements*(handle~))

to get the user email address

Unfortunately the first request always return:

```
{
    "serviceErrorCode": 100,
    "message": "Not enough permissions to access: GET /me",
    "status": 403
}
```

I have searched a lot here on stackoverflow and a lot suggest that you need to subscribe as partner  to get access to v2 api

here:
https://business.linkedin.com/marketing-solutions/marketing-partners/become-a-partner/marketing-developer-program

Linkedin in the migration guide says:

> **Does my developer application have access to the v2 API?** Any developer application created through the LinkedIn Developer Portal
>   after December 15, 2018 automatically has access to the v2 API.
>
> **What about existing developer applications?** If your developer application has made a successful v1 API request since October 1,
>   2018, your developer application automatically has access to the v2
>   API.

futhermore if I ask for the emailAddress v2 API, I get the correct response... so I don't think I need to compile the form the become a partner.

What should it be the problem?

Here the full path for authentication and API calls:

1) Go to auth page to request for permissions

```
window.location.href = "https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization?response_type=code" +
        "&client_id=" + linkedin_id + "&redirect_uri=" + redirect_uri +
        "&state=" + state + "&scope=r_basicprofile+r_emailaddress"
```

2) Retrieve the access token

```
request = ("https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken?grant_type=authorization_code&code=" +
                     code + "&redirect_uri=" +
                     redirect_uri + "&client_id="
                     + linkedin_id +
                     "&client_secret=" + linkedin_secret)

response = requests.get(request)
```

3) The access token is retrieved, we can request for user info **ALWAYS 403**

```
headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer "+token }
    get_user = requests.get('https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me', headers=headers)
```

4) Get user_email **working**

```
get_user_email = requests.get('https://api.linkedin.com/v2/emailAddress?q=members&projection=(elements*(handle~))', headers=headers)
```

Thanks

Comment: In your step 1, change `&scope=r_basicprofile+r_emailaddress` into `&scope=r_emailaddress+r_liteprofile`

Comment: @Vic thank you, after I have add r_liteprofile as scope and add it as a Default Application Permissions in the admin Linkedin application portal, it works! Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to use `r_liteprofile` instead of `r_basicprofile` if you only need the first name and last name

Comment: thank you, after I have add r_liteprofile as scope and add it as a Default Application Permissions in the admin Linkedin application portal, it works! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

change in step one :
&scope=r_basicprofile+r_emailaddress into 
&scope=r_liteprofile+r_emailaddress

call this :
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me?projection=(id,firstName,lastName,profilePicture(displayImage~:playableStreams))

Working for getting r_liteprofile  information 
you will get firstName, lastName, profilePicture, id

Answer (score 0):

You should pass '&scope=r_basicprofile+r_emailaddress' this at time of AccessToken Request

Step 1:
AccessToken  Requst will be like

```
https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken?grant_type=authorization_code&code={Your code}&redirect_uri={Yourredirect_uri}&client_id={Your client_id}&client_secret={Your client_secret }&scope=r_liteprofile+r_emailaddress
```

This will return you the AccessToken using which You do have to make 2 more request 
1 is for Email and Profile Details

Step 2:
for Email request will be like

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/emailAddress?q=members&projection=(elements*(handle~))&oauth2_access_token={AccessToken You get from step 1}'
```

Step 3:
for basic profile request will be like

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me?projection=(id,firstName,lastName,emailAddress,profilePicture(displayImage~:playableStreams))&oauth2_access_token={AccessToken You get from step 1}'
```